# How to organize scores into Pareto ranks with R?

Tags: r, ranking

I'm working block level census data to calculate social vulnerability index (SoVI), following a methodology by Cutter, 2003. 
I generated 4 principal components scores via PCA and I would like to use Pareto ranking to organize the block groups into a series of ranks ( as per Rygel et al. 2006: A method for constructing a social vulnerability Index).

I apologize that the question was unclear. Below is a sample dataset that I use, the rows representing block groups, and columns representing vulnerability dimensions(PCA components scores). I'd like to calculate the rank based on the 4 vulnerability dimensions, using Pareto method, in a new column.

```
sovi<-structure(list(deprivation = c(4.28, 4.91, 7.63, 
1.33,6.03,6.40,-0.21,6.72,-1.45,5.76), 
oldage = c(1.04,0.87,1.14,0.18,0.75,0.93,1.29,0.81,5.57,1.28),
housing = c(1.57, 1.41, 2.27, 0.21,0.97,2.65,-0.33,1.68,-1.72,1.78), 
education = c(-3.65,-1.73,-3.57,-3.37,-3.20,-2.06,-0.59,-2.93,-0.40,-3.09)), 
.Names = c("deprivation", "oldage", "housing", "education"),
row.names=c(NA,10L), class = "data.frame")
```

From Rygel, "The rationale behind the Pareto ranking method is as follows. Each case i is considered on the basis of a set of n component scores, {ci1, ci2, . . . , cin}. (...) it is assumed that a higher score on any individual component indicates greater vulnerability. When two (...) block groups A and B are compared, case A is more vulnerable than case B only if the scores for A are at least equal to those for B for all components and if there is at least one component on which A scores higher than B".

I searched the R website but wasn't able to find a package that does Pareto ranking.

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you be more precise...what do you want to do ?

Comment: I have a matrix of 2100 rows and 4 columns (my principal components, representing different dimensions of vulnerability). The values of the variables varies from ~ -10 to ~10, representing low vulnerability and high vulnerability, respectively. I'd like to group the rows into a series of ranks using Pareto ranking method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The definition you quote only defines a partial order: 
the more components you have, the fewer the comparable groups.

You can use a double loop, or `outer`, to compare all possible pairs of groups,
and `igraph` to plot the result.

```
n <- nrow(sovi)
a <- outer(1:n, 1:n, Vectorize( function(i,j) 
  all( sovi[i,] >= sovi[j,] ) && 
  any( sovi[i,] >  sovi[j,] ) 
) )
library(igraph)
g <- graph.adjacency(a)
plot(g)

# Remove the edges that can be inferred by transitivity
hasse <- function(g) {
  # Inspired from:
  #   http://web.bahcesehir.edu.tr/atabey_kaygun/other/hasse-local.html
  es <- get.edgelist(g)
  for( e in 1:nrow(es) ) { 
    i <- es[e,1]
    j <- es[e,2]
    g[i,j] <- FALSE
    p <- get.shortest.paths(g,i,j)
    if( length(p[[1]]) == 0 ) {
      g[i,j] <- TRUE 
    } else { 
      cat( "Removing edge ", i, "-", j, " because of ", paste(p[[1]],collapse="-"), "\n", sep="")
    }
  }
  g
}
plot(hasse(g))
```

[image: Graph of the partial order]